# Change the view in the Android Studio

Tags: android, button, layout, fragment

I try on another forum, thanks for answer but this was too hard tho!! :)

Comment: I'm sure you can get further help here If you choose the answer that looks the simplest to you and proceed to ask further questions to make sure that everything is clear. Also, it wasn't very clear what you wanted to do exactly, so the answers you got were a bit generic. You shouldn't expect a copy-paste answer to solve all your problems, unless you provide all the necessary code of your project, and explain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should create specific layout for your fragment in activity layout and specify its id in replace method. For more information read [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) documentation

Answer (score 0):

here is the documentation of [FragmentTransaction.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

The first parameter is the ID of the container view which contains your Fragments and not the ID of your layout

The second is the instance of the Fragment you want to display.

Generally, something like this is done :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one activity that contains a frameLayout with an id similar to fragment_container.

then from your activity you do the following:

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

that will place one fragment inside your Activity's layout. When you want to replace that, you just create the second fragment and do the same. If you want to make it easier just use it as a method:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and use it when you need to either display a fragment or swap one for an already displaying fragment. As Context use the activity that holds the fragments.

The idea is that you have one activity as a wrapper to the fragment. In its layout file you create a space for the fragment to be displayed, and with the above method, you replace the empty space with your fragment's layout. If you call it again with a different fragment in the arguments, it will automatically replace that space with the layout of the new fragment.

**EDIT:** If you want to switch back and forth using a button, add a button in your activity's layout and set an onClick listener. Then use a flag to choose which fragment to display.

boolean isFragmentOneDisplayed;

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFragmentOneDisplayed) {
                FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                replaceFragment(fragment, MainActivity.this);
                isFragmentOneDisplayed = false;
             } else {
                 FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
                 replaceFragment(fragment, MainActivity.this);
                 isFragmentOneDisplayed = true;
             }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have a frame layout in your main activity where you can place fragments and show to your users. That can be done like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

<FrameLayout

    android:id="@+id/frm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

Now in the frame layout (id = frm), you can place various fragments based on button clicks by your users. Now, by default place the first fragment in the frame layout and have a button in that fragment. Which can be done by adding the below line in your main activity:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frm,new FirstFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Once that button is clicked, you can write logic to replace the 1st fragment with 2nd fragment. Use the sample code below:

**Your 1st fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/litegrey">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/frag2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Go to fragment 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logic to move to next slide (this should be added in your 1st Fragment):**

```
frag2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frm,new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So, since I'm a very noob on this with fragments, I have some questions for some guidelines on this answer:

1. In the main activity, it occurs errors when adding the line with fragmentTransaction with "cannot resolve symbol. . . ."
2. For my first fragment, do you mean that I have to create a new layout for each fragment, I just wanna make sure that I understand what you mean.
3. Do you mean that I should create a new class for each fragment also?

Comment: 1.Which symbol was not resolved in your error ? `frm` or `FirstFragment` ? 2. Whenever you create a new fragment, it will be created with its own layout. You dont have to create it seperately. 3. Creating a fragment is very similar to creating an activity. Look for an option `fragment` in the same list where you will create an activity and click it. Android studio will create a new fragment with corresponding layout for that fragment for you.